# WPF INotifyPropertyChanged from non-ui thread

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a set of properties which are binding in my view, like:

```
private int _workDone;
public int WorkDone
{
   get{return _workDone;}
   set
   {
       _workDone = value;
       OnPropertyChanged();
   }

}
```

Now, this property is binding to my progress bar and it's being changed from a non-ui thread, problem is the whole progress bar goes from 0 to 100 in a second, am I allowed to raise INotifyPropertyChanged from non-ui threads?

Comment: One thing the linked answer doesn't mention: for progress reporting, use a `Progress<T>`/`IProgress<T>`. That will handle the dispatch back to the main thread for you

Comment: @canton7 i still don't get it , shouldn't InotifyPropertyChanged be activated evenn if called from a non ui thread?

Comment: Maybe. It does sound like you're blocking the UI thread rather than doing your work on a non-UI thread, but without any code it's impossible to say

Comment: @canton7 I've update the question here if you wanna take a look at the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74775928/wpf-mvvm-ui-not-updating-properly-from-thread-even-when-raising-inotifypropert