# WPF MVVM - UI not updating properly from thread even when raising INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm reading a file byte-by-byte and trying to update my progress bar accordingly using MVVM.
Here's what I did so far.

The File Model is just a single class storing the file path, total number of bytes and number of bytes read so far which I called WorkDone and it's what im using as the current value of the progress bar.

### File Model:

```
public class TestingFile : ObservableObject
    {

        private string _filePath;

        public string FilePath
        {
            get { return _filePath; }
            set
            {
                _filePath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private byte[] _fileContent;

        public byte[] FileContent
        {
            get { return _fileContent; }
            set 
            {
                _fileContent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

     

        private int _workDone;
        // how many bytes have been read
        public int WorkDone
        {
            get { return _workDone; }
            set
            {
                _workDone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private int _totalLen;
        // total bytes
        public int TotalLen
        {
            get { return _totalLen; }
            set 
            { 
                _totalLen = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }



        public void StartRead()
        {
            FileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
            TotalLen = FileContent.Length;

            ReadTestingFile();

        }


        void ReadTestingFile()
        {
            WorkDone = 0;

            foreach (byte currentByte in _fileContent)
            {
                // do some stuff here for each byte in the file

                ++WorkDone; // update progress bar
            }
        }


    }
```

The view model has a TestingFile object and gets it from a filedialog, after getting the selected file it calls the **StartRead** method shown below to read the file:

### View Model:

```
   public class FirstViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private TestingFile myTestingFile { get; set; }
        public TestingFile MyTestingFile
        {
            get { return myTestingFile; }
            set
            { 
                myTestingFile  = value; 
            }
        }

        public ICommand GetFileCommand { get; set; }
        public FirstViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            GetFileCommand = new RelayCommand(GetFileDialog);

            MyTestingFile = new TestingFile();
        }

 
        public void GetFileDialog()
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                MyTestingFile.FilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyTestingFile.StartRead));
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

    }
```

Now , in the view I just create a progress bar and bind it's value to WorkDone and Maximum value to TotalLen from the model:

### The view:

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Margin="200, 20, 200, 0"
                             Value="{Binding MyTestingFile.WorkDone, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             Maximum="{Binding MyTestingFile.TotalLen}"
                             Height="25"/>
```

The problem is that, even though I'm creating a separate thread for reading the file, the progress bar is not moving as the file is being read, it goes directly to 100 after the whole file is read, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change notification has thread affinity. You need to dispatcher invokeasync your value. You should also do so each one hundredth of the file size rather than once a byte if these are going to be big.

Comment: Not delegating. Maybe BackgroundWorker class would be a better approach.

Comment: Neither explicitly creating a Thread nor BackgroundWorker is a good approach today. Use async/await, e.g. with Task.Run .

Comment: Eldhasp might have a point. My assumption was that these must be big files and complex processing. If you clicked the button and it instantly jumped to done then you'd not be able to tell the difference. Fwiw inpc is supposed to automatically marshall change notification. In my experience though, that is not always reliable. I have never had the need to work out exactly why. I guess maybe many changes in a tight loop might cause a problem.

Comment: @Andy yeah, I intend to use this for large files, for small files I was not able to tell the difference

Comment: You should look into async await. Including File.readallbytesasync.  but first, try a big file. Divide your file size by 100 and only increment your value once you've done each hundredth. Maybe giving it a little time to automatically marshall will do the trick. If not then iterate.

Comment: I was curious about the marshaling. That works by appending to the dispatcher queue. That queue is a priority queue and it handles all ui updates. Including rendering. According to something I read, binding value transfer has a higher priority than rendering. My theory: If you make many changes to a value in a tight loop those values propagate but there's another value change before rendering. Then another. Until you hit max and it gets a chance to render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not in the implementation, but in your expectations.
You expect the value of the WorkDone property to gradually change. This value is incremented in a loop in the ReadTestingFile method. The problem is that this cycle takes place almost instantly - in units or even fractions of a millisecond.
Therefore, you do not even have time to see intermediate values, but only see the final result.

For testing purposes, add a small delay to the method:

```cs
        void ReadTestingFile()
        {
            WorkDone = 0;

            foreach (byte currentByte in _fileContent)
            {
                // do some stuff here for each byte in the file

                ++WorkDone; // update progress bar

               Thread.Sleep(10); // Testing MUST not be on the UI thread!
            }
        }
```

**P.S.**  I also advise you to use asynchronous methods and Task instead of Thread.

```cs
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                MyTestingFile.FilePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                Task.Run(MyTestingFile.StartRead);
            }
```

**SUPPLEMENT:**

> but what about larger files ...?

If you need it for large files, then you need to reduce the refresh rate.
An example of such an implementation:

```cs
void ReadTestingFile()
{
    int _workDone = WorkDone = 0;
    byte[] _fileContent = FileContent;
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(20);
        } while ((WorkDone = _workDone) != _fileContent.Length);
    });
    foreach (byte currentByte in _fileContent)
    {
        // do some stuff here for each byte in the file

        _workDone++; // update progress bar
    }
}
```

**P.S.** But I'm warning you right now.
For greater security, it is better to cancel the task using CancellationToken. In my example, I did using conditional checking to simplify the code for this example.

Comment: but what about larger files, which take more time to process, shouldn't I be able to see the progressbar gradually grow in this case?

Comment: Each increment of the counter takes a very short time. Each one raises the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event. During rendering, they accumulate so much that the UI simply does not have time to process them and freezes.

Comment: @Slava , Read the supplement to my answer.

Comment: @Slava , Have you been able to use the proposed option in practice?